# What is the name for this chart which splits a quantity by allocation to a class hierarchy?

Tags: infographics

I need to create this type of chart, where you can see a quantity is split into a hierarchy of classes or taxonomy. In the example below the quantity is a household monthly income, and the classes are different monthly expenditures, classified broadly to the left, and progressively split into more detailed sub-classes.

However, I don't know what it is called and thus cannot find which tool to use.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called a Sankey-Diagram:
"Sankey diagrams are a specific type of flow diagram, in which the width of the arrows is shown proportionally to the flow quantity." ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram)

An easy package to make these graphs would be "d3Network" in R. But many other options are available.

Comment: I first read that as "Snakey-Diagram"